# (node) Hit max file limit?

Tags: linux, node.js, ulimit

I keep getting an error in my node.js instance where it reports the error:

```
(node) Hit max file limit. Increase "ulimit - n"
```

Yet when I check my ulimit -n, it says 65535.
There is no way in hell my app is opening 65535 connections. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on what else to check?

Cheers

Comment: posting some code would help.

Comment: are you opening files or connections ? do you close them explicitly, or do you rely on a destructor called by a GC to do it ? do you create them in a loop ? Keep in mind that a GC will close them "later", where "later" can be after 1000 iteration of a loop where you create 100 of them, use them and discard them, so you could have 100000 open file descriptors in a short time if you don't close them when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: try a 'ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd' with the pid of the process before it dies, then you'll see what file descriptors are open.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set the limits in [/etc/security/limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) file. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html) is a "how to" guide to set the limits within the file (in your case it should be **nofile** value).